# How to push notification to browser using node JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

I follow [this](http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/nodejs-and-a-simple-push-notification-server/) sample code to push notification to browser, I follow the instructions and run the app using `node server.js` and I open the browser and run `localhost:8000` and change text in example.xml and save it then the text pushed to browser (appear on screen browser).

But I still don't get it to implement to another app server, what I mean, for example I have a app using ruby on rails then I run the server on `localhost:3000`.

So now I have 2 running servers, first node.js app on `localhost:8000` and second one my rails app on `localhost:3000`.

So how to pass notification from my node.js app to my rails app ?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Redis or similar message queue for inter process communication.

Rails Push to Redis Queue.
http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html

Node Reads off Redis queue
https://github.com/mranney/node_redis